# How to make Python Yaml library save in a human-friendly way?

Tags: python, file, configuration, yaml, human-readable

Here is the Python code I've got:

```
d = {'ToGoFirst': 'aaa', 'Second': 'bbb', 'Pagargaph':
'''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.''',  
'Integer': 25}
with open('d.yaml', 'w') as f:
    yaml.safe_dump(d, f, default_flow_style=False)
```

What I keep getting:

```
Integer: 25
Pagargaph: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \nconsectetur adipiscing elit, \nsed do eiusmod\
  \ tempor incididunt \nut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
Second: bbb
ToGoFirst: aaa
```

How do I change it to produce:

```
ToGoFirst: aaa
Second: bbb
Pagargaph: 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  consectetur adipiscing elit, 
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Integer: 25
```

In other words I want to:

1. Avoid quotation marks and escape characters in the output so non-technical users can read and edit those config files.
2. Ideally preserve the order of parameters.

This is to be able to load a YAML file, add more parameters and still be able to save it in a human-friendly format.

Comment: Your example of expected/desired output is wrong. You can't produce what you have in a plain scalar. You have multiple lines with trailing spaces, and pyyaml decides to use double quotes for this. The alternative would be a literal block scalar.

Comment: The order of parameters might be preserved in one of the next version of pyyaml (when run with python 3.6/3.7). currently it always sorts the keys, but there is a [pull request](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/pull/143) to allow disabling it. alternatively try ruamel.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output has no newlines in the value for `Pagargaph`, for that you would need to have a [block-style literal scalar](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688) (the dash trims the final newline, you would normally get when loading such a scalar):

```
Pagargaph: |-
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  consectetur adipiscing elit, 
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

You should use [`ruamel.yaml`](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), which is specifically developed to support this kind of round-tripping. To get what you want do e.g.:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import PreservedScalarString as L

yaml_str = """\
ToGoFirst: aaa
Second: 'bbb'  # insert after this one
Integer: 25
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
d = yaml.load(yaml_str)
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
try:
    before_integer = [k for k in d].index('Integer')
except ValueError:
    before_integer = len(d)
d.insert(before_integer, 'Pagargaph', L('''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'''))  
d.insert(before_integer, 'Something', 'extra', comment='with a comment')
yaml.dump(d, sys.stdout)
```

resulting in:

```
ToGoFirst: aaa
Second: 'bbb'  # insert after this one
Something: extra # with a comment
Pagargaph: |-
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
  consectetur adipiscing elit, 
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Integer: 25
```

Please note:

- the order is preserved in any version of Python supported by ruamel.yaml (2.7, 3.4+)
- the comment is preserved
- the quotes that I added around `bbb` are preserved only if you specify `yaml.preserve_quotes = True`
- since we insert twice at position 2, the latter bumps the former to position 3.

Your users will have to be a bit disciplined for them to be able to edit a YAML file and not break it. They should also know some of the caveats, such as that plain (non-quoted) scalars, cannot start with some special characters or contain special character sequences (`:` followed by space, `#` preceded by space)

To help prevent your users from making editing mistakes, you can try to add the following comment at the beginning of the YAML document:

```
# please read the first few "rules" of How_to_edit at the bottom of this file
```

and at the end:

```
How_to_edit: |
 Editing a YAML document is easy, but there are some rules to keep you from 
 accidently invoking its hidden powers. Of the following you need at least 
 read and apply the ones up to the divider separating the important from less 
 important rules. The less important ones are interesting, but you probably 
 won't need to know them.
 1) Entries in this file consist of a scalar key (before the ':') and a scalar 
    value (normally after the ':', but read rule 3). 
 2) Scalars do NOT need quotes (single: ', or double: ") around them, unless 
    you have a special character or characters combinations at the beginning 
    ('%', '*', '&', '{', '[', '- ') or in the middle  (': ', ' #) of the  scalar.
    If you add quotes use a single quote before and after the scalar . If 
    these are superfluous the program can remove them. So when in doubt just 
    add them.
 3) A key followed by ': |' introduces a multiline scalar. These instructions
    are in a multiline scalar. Such a scalar starts on the next line after ': |'.
    The lines need to be indented, until the end of the scalar and these 
    indentation spaces are not part of the scalar. 
    The newlines in a multiline sclar are hard (i.e. preserved, and not 
    substituted with spaces).
    If you see `: |-` that means the scalar is loaded with the trailing newline 
    stripped.
 4) Anything after a space followed by a hash (' #') is a comment, when not 
    within quotes or in a multiline string.
 --- end of the important rules ---
 5) Within single quoted scalars you can have a single quote by doubling it: 
       rule 4: 'you probably don''t ever need that'
    This is called escaping the single quote. You can double quote scalars, but 
    the rules for escaping are much more difficult, so don't try that at home.
 6) The scalars consisting solely of "True" and "False" (also all-caps and 
    all-lowercase) are loaded as booleans when unquoted, and as strings when 
    quoted. 
 7) Scalars consisting solely of number characters (0-9) are loaded as numbers.
    If there is a non-number they are usually loaded as strings, but scalars 
    starting with '0x' and '0o' and for the rest have only number characters,
    are special and need quotes if not intended as (hexadecimal resp. octal) 
    numbers.
```

If you include the above, you probably don't want to preserve quotes when round-tripping.

Comment: Thank you. Can I get rid of "|-" but still satisfy the YAML specification?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you won't have any newlines in your scalar, the newlines that you see, and all following white space at the beginning of the line will be replaced with a space. And that would not be the same as your "Lorem ipsum ..." which has three embeded newlines (now of course that might not make a difference for your application, but that I can't know).

Comment: I mean can I somehow get rid of "|-" and still have newlines? In other words, how can I make the output entirely nontechie-friendly?

Comment: You can't. Your techies have to learn some stuff, like when to quote and when not, that they need to indent, etc. as well. If you're data structure only consists of a root level mapping (no nested mappings and sequences), you should be able to parse that with some preprocessing, but you might as well parse without YAML in that case.

Comment: I updated my answer with a suggestion on adding basic editing instructions. They are not complete though.